# How to split string from a QR Code and inserting them into a login and password text form field

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to create a scanner that can insert string from a QR code. I've been researching to no avail.

I managed to create a simple scanner that can setstate for the username text form field but not sure how to split the string from the qr code to do the same for the password text form field.

Below is my current code.

For the form

```
               ListTile(
                    title: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.length < 1 ? 'Username Required' : null,
                      onSaved: (val) => _username = val,
                      obscureText: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _controllerUsername, //controller
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                      validator: (val) =>
                          val.length < 1 ? 'Password Required' : null,
                      onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: _controllerPassword,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      autocorrect: false,
                    ),
                  ),
```

And this is the scanner

```
            ListTile(
              title: NativeButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Scan',
                    textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    scan().then((string) => setState(() {
                          _controllerUsername.text = _username;
                          _controllerPassword.text = _password;
                        }));
                  }),
            )


 Future<void> scan() async {
    try {
      String _username = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#ff6666', //bg color
        'Cancel',
        true,
        ScanMode.QR,
      );

      if (!mounted) return;

      setState(() {
        this._username = _username.isEmpty
            ? ''
            : _username == '-1'
                ? ''
                : _username;
      });
    } on PlatformException {
      _username = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
  }
```

### Edit

I used an online QR Code generator and write text such as name~password and the result shows up the same in username text form field.

Comment: Please write QR code result string here and Who generates the QR code?

Comment: I used qr code generator and used free-text with examples such as "name~password" and the result in the username text field form is also "name~password".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate the QR code then this is the simple and best way to achieve your requirement

```
 import 'dart:convert';

 Map<String, dynamic> user = {
                              'name': "Test",
                              'password': "password",
                              'email': "example@gmail.com",
 };
 
String userDate = json.encode(user);
```

Use userDate to  generate QR code

After scan convert QR into Map

```
var userInfo = json.decode(userDate);
```

get required field like this

```
print(userInfo['name']);
```

Comment: So with these I need to use libraries like QR_Flutter to manually create the QR code?

Comment: Yes, use any QR code generator library

Comment: Understood, thank you!